# Can you find the next entry in this sequence `?`

Tags: pattern

**Find a rule that applies for the first six entries** and add at least one more.

```
I
```

```
do
```

```
take
```

```
20,000¥
```

```
recompensations
```

The rule is simple.

Each individual entry has multiple valid solution, this is just one such set. The fact that the next entry is longer than the previous one doesn't need to be true for all entries.

Comment: Next words: `in` `lieu` `of` `pre-determined` `donut` `payment`.

Comment: @IanMacDonald why would you think that? I'm curious.

Comment: Is the trailing space after recompensations significant?

Comment: @ScottM Yes it is.

Comment: I cannot see any meaningful similarities amongst the words apart from them grammatically forming the beginning of a sentence when taken in the order provided. I have simply chosen to finish the sentence as though this were a court case involving a dispute about missing donuts.

Comment: “The fact that the next entry is longer than the previous one doesn’t need to be true for all entries.” is borderline misleading.  I guess you mean that something like “t̲⁠h̲⁠e̲ ̲̲p̲o̲n̲y̲” would qualify?

Comment: @PeregrineRook you can write something like☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼↕¶... if you want. The readability of the entries is for the purpose of readability. Or to distract you. The goal is to find the rule by noticing the trailing space after the last entry and the fact that yen symbol holds two bytes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about

> at every opportunity that I can.

Each line

> is double the byte count of the previous one.

Comment: Very Nice.Short and precise.Lovely.

Comment: This leads me to believe that `in lieu of agreed donut payment.` would also be an acceptable solution. If that is the case, this puzzle is not specific enough and has far too many possible correct answers.

Comment: @IanMacDonald The question is to find the rule. Which is unique. A hidden trailing space after the last entry hints toward the rule itself. It is stated that multiple valid solutions can replace the existing entries.

Comment: @Vepir: But [the rule *isn't* unique](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C4%2C8%2C16&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: @Deusovi If you consider the fact we are dealing with bytes, which leads to binary, which leads to powers of 2, which is the rule; And the fact the the rule is simple. But I guess nothing is unique if you try to fit things like "*a(n)=2a(n-1), except every tenth time you multiply by 1000/512 instead of by 2*" ? or something like: a(1) = 1; for n>1, a(n) is the smallest positive integer not already present which is entailed by the rules (i) k present => 2k present; (ii) 3k+1 present and k odd => k present., // which is among "similar sequences".

Comment: Well, the sequence "Maximum number of regions a circle can be divided into by n lines" goes 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, **31**. (Besides, there's nothing saying we *have* to count bytes rather than characters - there are many 1,2,4,7,16 sequences too, and 1,2,4,7,15 if we ignore whitespace.)

Comment: @Deusovi Guess the numbers are just popular. And I'm not suprised since we are dealing with powers of: the only pair prime / the smallest prime / smallest integer number base / smallest pair number / most popular integer exponent / 3rd fibonacchi number / 2nd Catalan number / 2nd bell number / 2nd Motzkin number / exponent of smallest Mersenne prime / smallest integer representation in 2 squares /... etc.

Comment: ...Yes, you've described the number 2 in many different ways. That doesn't change the fact that the sequence doesn't *have* to be powers of two, especially with so few data points (some of which are ambiguous!)

Comment: @Deusovi I guess you are right when it comes to number sequences of this kind. But If I hadn't posted this question as it is, we would've never  had had this likeable conversation.